# JavaSwing add multiple JTable to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, jscrollpane

I am working on java swing application.I have to browse multiple CSV data files and display them into JFrame using JTable.I am trying to add multiple(non static) JTable into JFrame.All (N) JTable i want to include inside a JSrollPane.At this moment i can display only 1 table to JScrollPane.

Thanks in advance!

```
if (e.getSource() == jbtreadbrowsefile) {

            try {

                for(int k=0;k<file_locations.length;k++) {

                    String currentLocation=file_locations[k];
                    inputList = new ArrayList();
                    File inputF = new File(currentLocation);
                    InputStream inputFS = new FileInputStream(inputF);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputFS));
                    inputList = br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
                    br.close();

                       int count = inputList.size();

                       if(count>0)
                       {
                           data = new String[count - 1][8];
                           for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {

                           String[] arrOfStr = inputList.get(i + 1).toString().split(",");
                           String test1= arrOfStr[0];
                           String test2= arrOfStr[1];
                           String test3= arrOfStr[2];
                           String test4 = arrOfStr[3];
                           String test5= arrOfStr[4];
                           String test6= arrOfStr[5];
                           String test7= arrOfStr[6];

                           data[i][0] = "" + (i + 1);
                           data[i][1] = test1;
                           data[i][2] = test2;
                           data[i][3] = test3;
                           data[i][4] = test4;
                           data[i][5] = test5;
                           data[i][6] = test6;
                           data[i][7] = test7;

                       }

                       j = new JTable(data, columnNames);
                       TableColumnModel tcm = j.getColumnModel();
                       tcm.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(40);
                       tcm.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(220);
                       tcm.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(120);
                       tcm.getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(80);
                       tcm.getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(80);
                       tcm.getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(80);
                       tcm.getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(80);
                       tcm.getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(80);

                       DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
                       centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                       j.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);

                       for (int i = 0; i < j.getRowCount(); i++) {
                           j.setRowHeight(i, 20);
                       }

                       j.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 15));
                       j.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
                       j.repaint();



                       JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(j); 
                       sp.setBounds(10, 200, 780, 440);
                       add(sp);



                       }
                   else
                       {
                           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"No Data Found in the File");
                       }


                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For displaying each JTable into JFrame,i added all JTable into a JPanel and added this JPanel into JScrollPane.After displaying each JTable the problem was that we can not display each JTable header.I added to another JPanel each JTable header and it's shows up.

```
if (e.getSource() == jbtreadbrowsefile) {

            GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(0, 1, 30, 20);
            jpaneltable=new JPanel(grid);
            try {

                for(int k=0;k<file_locations.length;k++) {

                    String currentLocation=file_locations[k];
                    inputList = new ArrayList();
                    File inputF = new File(currentLocation);
                    InputStream inputFS = new FileInputStream(inputF);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputFS));
                    inputList = br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
                    br.close();

                       int count = inputList.size();

                       if(count>0)
                       {
                           data = new String[count - 1][8];
                           for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {

                           String[] arrOfStr = inputList.get(i + 1).toString().split(",");
                           String test1= arrOfStr[0];
                           String test2= arrOfStr[1];
                           String test3= arrOfStr[2];
                           String test4= arrOfStr[3];
                           String test5= arrOfStr[4];
                           String test6= arrOfStr[5];
                           String test7= arrOfStr[6];

                           data[i][0] = "" + (i + 1);
                           data[i][1] = test1;
                           data[i][2] = test2;
                           data[i][3] = test3;
                           data[i][4] = test4;
                           data[i][5] = test5;
                           data[i][6] = test6;
                           data[i][7] = test7;

                       }

                       j = new JTable(data, columnNames);
                       TableColumnModel tcm = j.getColumnModel();
                       tcm.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(40);
                       tcm.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(220);
                       tcm.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(120);
                       tcm.getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(80);
                       tcm.getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(80);
                       tcm.getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(80);
                       tcm.getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(80);
                       tcm.getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(80);

                       DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
                       centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                       j.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);

                       for (int i = 0; i < j.getRowCount(); i++) {
                           j.setRowHeight(i, 20);
                       }

                       j.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 15));
                       j.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);

                       j.getTableHeader().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,HEADER_HEIGHT));
                       j.repaint();


                       jpaneltable.add(j.getTableHeader(),BorderLayout.NORTH);
                       jpaneltable.add(j, BorderLayout.CENTER);


                       }
                   else
                       {
                           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"No Data Found in the File");
                       }


                }

                JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(jpaneltable,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED); 
                sp.setBounds(10, 200, 780, 440);
                add(sp);



            }
```

Comment: *at we can not display each JTable header.* - you add the JTable to a separate JScrollPane and then add the scroll pane to the panel. Each table must be added to its own scroll pane if you want to see the header.

Answer (score 1):

```
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(j); 
sp.setBounds(10, 200, 780, 440);
add(sp);
```

Don't use setBounds(). It is the job of the layout manager to determine the size/location of a component.

> At this moment i can display only 1 table to JScrollPane.

Correct. A JScrollPane is designed to display a single JTable. The header of the JTable will be displayed at the header view of the scroll pane and the table will be displayed in the center of the scroll pane. You may then also see scrollbars in the scroll pane depending on the data in the table.

If you want to "merge" data from multiple files into the same table, then you need to update the TableModel with the data from each file instead of creating a new table each time.

You can dynamically add data to the model by using the `addRow(…)` method of the `DefaultTableModel`.

Comment: I was looking for this answer and you are right.This is a better way to fulfill my needs but at this moment i should display CSV data files in seperate JTable and i solve it.I will post and answer my question and for future user i think it will be better if accepted answer it will be my own answer because it is related directly to question.I have a small problem now and i will appreciate if you can help with that.I can not change table header for each JTable.Thank you!